# How do i overwrite my txt file each time its updated in Python

Tags: python, youtube

So i have this script that uses **REGEX** to keep track of when a youtube channel has uploaded a new video. and the code works fine but my issue is when i'm storing the video's title, view's etc of the *latest video*. and sending that data off to a txt to compare it for later to see if there is an update. my txt file is appending the name and views of the vids instead of overwriting it.
here is my code

```
list = [] <br />
newvid = [] <br />
def Update_txt(): <br />
    with open('Youtube.txt', "w") as f:
        f.writelines('\n'.join(newvid).split(","))

with open('Youtube.txt','r+') as r: <br />
    for line in r:
        newvid.append(line.strip())<br />
channel = "https://www.youtube.com/c/MikeKorzemba2K"

html = requests.get(channel + "/videos").text <br />
info = re.search('(?<={"label":").*?(?="})', html).group()<br />
date = re.search('\d+ \w+ ago.*seconds ', info).group()<br />
newvid.append("Mike Korzemba")<br />
list.append("Mike Korzemba")<br />
newvid.append(info)<br />
list.append(info)<br />



channel1 = "https://www.youtube.com/c/JxmyHighroller"
html = requests.get(channel1 + "/videos").text
info1 = re.search('(?<={"label":").*?(?="})', html).group()
newvid.append("Jxmy")
list.append("Jxmy")
newvid.append(info1)
list.append(info1)

channel2 = "https://www.youtube.com/c/ThinkingBasketball" <br />
html = requests.get(channel2 + "/videos").text<br />
info2 = re.search('(?<={"label":").*?(?="})', html).group()<br />
newvid.append("Thinking Basketball")<br />
list.append("Thinking Basketball")<br />
newvid.append(info2)<br />
list.append(info2)<br />



channel3 = "https://www.youtube.com/c/LegendOfWinningNBA"<br />
html = requests.get(channel3 + "/videos").text<br />
info3 = re.search('(?<={"label":").*?(?="})', html).group()<br />
newvid.append("Legend of Winning")<br />
list.append("Legend of Winning")<br />

newvid.append(info3)<br />
list.append(info3)<br />


channel4 = "https://www.youtube.com/c/bballbreakdown"<br />
html = requests.get(channel4 + "/videos").text<br />
info4 = re.search('(?<={"label":").*?(?="})', html).group()<br />
newvid.append("BBALL BREAKDOWN!")<br />
list.append("BBALL BREAKDOWN!")<br />
newvid.append(info4)<br />
list.append(info4)<br />

channel5 = "https://www.youtube.com/c/Hamza97"<br />
html = requests.get(channel5 + "/videos").text<br />
info5 = re.search('(?<={"label":").*?(?="})', html).group()<br />
newvid.append("Hamza")<br />
list.append("Hamza")<br />
newvid.append(info5)<br />
list.append(info5)<br />



channel6 = "https://www.youtube.com/c/SwishOut"<br />
html = requests.get(channel6 + "/videos").text<br />
info6 = re.search('(?<={"label":").*?(?="})', html).group()<br />
newvid.append("SWISHH OUT")<br />
list.append("SWISHH OUT")<br />

newvid.append(info6)<br />
list.append(info6)<br />

Update_txt()<br />

if newvid[0] == list[0]:<br />
    pass<br />
elif newvid[0] != list[0]:<br />
    #send_txt_Message(os.getenv("Number")," The txt file name has been updated from" + newvid[0] + " to " + list[0])

    Mike = list[0]
    newvid[0] = Mike
```

'Update_txt()'```

this line of code is supposed to update ( overwrite) the txt file if the data has changed. i didnt include the rest of my code as its repitive after this. basically check each newvid[] index item and compare it with list[] at same position and see if there is change. for reference i got the rege code from this question and if anyone can tell me how to only keep track of the videos title and not the view count and date posted would appreciate it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101221/how-to-get-notification-when-youtube-channel-uploads-video-in-python

**UPDATE******
It seems when i remove this block of code `with open('Youtube.txt','r+') as r:  for line in r: newvid.append(line.strip())`

it stops appending to the txt file and just overwrites it. thats weird tho cuz the 'w' Mode should be overwriting the "Youtube.txt" file if it exists anyways ... weird any input appreciated.

Comment: with open(filename,'w')  will erase before writing anything in it, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes thats what im looking for , and ive put it in "w" mode but it seems to just append to the txt file each time instead of clearing it and starting fresh :(

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file in write mode will automatically delete the file's contents.

Therefore use the `w` parameter to open your file like:

```
with open(filename.txt, 'w'):
    # your code here
```

Comment: Hey, so i edited my Question as my code actually already had it in " w  " mode it still doesn't clear the txt file each time and overwrite it as i want it too.